# When will Ubuntu One for Windows be released?

Tags: windows, ubuntu-one

I wanted to know when will the Windows version of Ubuntu one be available? Does anyone have any information about it?

Comment: Ha, I like how on the Ubuntu One site that section starts with, *"Recognizing that many of us are sometimes forced to use legacy operating systems..."*

Answer (score 6):

We will be releasing a public beta of the Windows client within the next couple weeks. When it's ready, we'll be sure to announce it on the Ubuntu One blog: http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone

Answer (score 5):

Ahem... allow me to quote:

> Recognizing that many of us are sometimes forced to use legacy operating systems, Ubuntu One is coming to the rescue. You're invited to beta test our new [Windows client](https://one.ubuntu.com/windows/beta) for syncing files — just sign up for our [free Ubuntu One Basic plan](https://one.ubuntu.com/plans/) and [install the software](https://one.ubuntu.com/windows/beta) to contribute.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ubuntu One Roadmap](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Roadmap) says that "Windows file sync" is coming as part of the Ubuntu 10.10 release:

> **Windows file sync**
>
> - Addresses the needs of the many
>     Ubuntu users who operate in a mixed
>     platform environment of Ubuntu +
>     Windows
> - Will support syncing files
>     between Windows desktops and your
>     Ubuntu One personal cloud

Also, see the the [**Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter**, Issue 208 for the week **August 22nd - August 28th, 2010.**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue208#Ubuntu%20One%20taking%20care%20of%20Windows%20users%20...%20not%20so%20much%20users%20of%20other%20Linux%20distributions), which says:

> **Ubuntu One taking care of Windows users ... not so much users of other
>   Linux distributions**
>
> Steven Rosenberg, of Tech Talk
>   discusses Ubuntu One. A look at the
>   roadmap for Ubuntu One reveals the
>   following feature planned for Maverick
>   — Windows file sync: Addresses the
>   needs of the many Ubuntu users who
>   operate in a mixed platform
>   environment of Ubuntu + Windows ...
>   Will support syncing files between
>   Windows desktops and your Ubuntu One
>   personal cloud ... I wonder, what
>   about a free, open-source Ubuntu One
>   client that could be used in any Linux
>   distribution?
>
> To read the full article go to:
>   http://www.insidesocal.com/click/2010/08/ubuntu-one-taking-care-of-wind.html

Comment: The client _is_ free, open source and written in Python. There is nothing to prevent all other distros for using it, but packaging software for other distros is not Ubuntus job. It's much more difficult to make it available on systems like Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question on one of the Ubuntu One developer's [blog](http://blogs.gnome.org/rodrigo/2010/07/06/ubuntu-one-syncdaemon-api/).

It turns out that there is work underway, but no date as of the time I asked.

Comment: @Giuliano , that blog entry is a little old. I believe I found some more recent information. See my post below.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One for Windows (XP, Vista, Win7 and Win8) has been released. It may be downloaded from [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows).

Answer (score 0):

It already has according to their website:

https://one.ubuntu.com/plans/

But only for subscribers.

Comment: I think his is just for contact sync

Answer (score 0):

*We are also extending our platform support to include a Windows client, which will be available in Beta very soon.*

http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=617

Answer (score -1):

Can we just assume that DropBox is the immediate solution: More space, less price, works on windows/linux/mac. I know its not a real "answer" but its my reason for not using ubuntu one. Also I could not even get it working since I think it wants some special Firefox plugin.